# For Each Worksheet in Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Any thoughts on why the below code would not be looping through the worksheets?

I'm trying to set a column in each sheet based on what the sheet name is. It's getting stuck on the active worksheet, and ignoring the `If ws.Name <> "Default"`. This is built as a module:

```
Sub LangID_update()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Default" Then

LastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range(Cells(2, LastCol + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1))
    With rng
        For Each c In Range(Cells(2, LastCol + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1))
            If ws.Name = "ARGS" Then c.Value = "ESP"
            If ws.Name = "AUTS" Then c.Value = "GR"
            If ws.Name = "DEUS" Then c.Value = "GR"

        Next c
    End With
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Many of the object refences that you are using are unqualified and therefore refer to the active sheet. Add the `ws.` object qualification at the beginning of each object.

Answer (score 3):

You would probably want to explicitly declare your `rng` range's worksheet. (I'm assuming it's going to be in the `ws`).

Try this:

```
Sub LangID_update()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Default" Then

LastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, LastCol + 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1))
    With rng
        For Each c In rng
            If ws.Name = "ARGS" Then c.Value = "ESP"
            If ws.Name = "AUTS" Then c.Value = "GR"
            If ws.Name = "DEUS" Then c.Value = "GR"

        Next c
    End With
    End If
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Edit: I'm also pretty sure you don't need the `with rng` since you loop through it with a `for` loop, and don't necessarily use `rng.____` in the `With` statement.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are not referencing the ws variable when accessing the ranges.

```
Set rng = Range(ws.Cells(2, LastCol + 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1))
For Each c In rng
```

Notice: when you dont add a sheet qualification for the ranges and cells, they are taken from the ActiveSheet. That is why your code was stuck on the ActiveSheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `For Each` line is bugged, but without seeing what's behind, it's hard to say.

```
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Default" Then

LastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'next line is useless
'Set rng = Range(Cells(2, LastCol + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1))
    With rng
        '             qualify Range and Cells
        For Each c In ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, LastCol + 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1))
            If ws.Name = "ARGS" Then c.Value = "ESP"
            If ws.Name = "AUTS" Then c.Value = "GR"
            If ws.Name = "DEUS" Then c.Value = "GR"

        Next c
    End With
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

The answers thus far have been spot on: the problem is the lack of qualification for `rng` in the for block.  That said though, a quick addition of one line will solve the issue:

`If ws.Name <> "Default" Then
    ws.Activate`

Activating the worksheet will make the rest of the code go fine, since you're on/thinking about the active sheet, and you just made that one light up.