# vba import cells from other workbooks error

Tags: vba, excel, range, copy-paste, cells

I am trying to copy some range of cells from other workbooks, but I get the error:

```
'runtime '1004' error 
Error defined by application or object
```

if I try to use the "range(cells(i,j), cells(k,h))" sintax instead of the range("A1:Z1"). I.e., In the following code the line "PASTE 1" produces an error, while the line "PASTE 2" runs smoothly (obviously I don't want to use the second one because I need to run a loop over different ranges).

```
Sub Importa()

Dim directory As String
Dim fileName  As String
Dim wbfrom    As Workbook
Dim wbto    As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "mydirectory"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")   'find the first *.xl?? file; '  wildcards: multiple character (*) single character (?)
Set wbto = ThisWorkbook
Set wbfrom = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName, False, True)

' copy some cells
wbfrom.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(9, 6), Cells(15, 6)).Copy

'PASTE 1
wbto.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(15, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'PASTE 2
'wbto.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


wbfrom.Close SaveChanges:=False
'Turn on screen updating and displaying alerts again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome, this question is very similar to one asked just today.  Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041178/vba-for-each-worksheet-in-workbook)

Comment: Very similar, good catch @ScottCraner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you need to qualify the `Cells` to a particular sheet/workbook. Otherwise, it is implictly belonging to the `ActiveSheet`, and since the `wbFrom` is Active at run-time, the range cannot exist (because cells on one worksheet cannot define a range on another worksheet)

Two ways to handle this, one is qualifying `Cells` like so:

```
With wbto.Sheets(1)
    .Range(.Cells(9, 1), .Cells(15, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
```

The other is to coerce the address from the cells:

```
wbto.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(9, 1).Address, Cells(15, 1).Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

My preference is for the first option, as it tends to be more dynamic and easy to read and modify later, if you need to do so.